# How to visually disable checkbox in SWT.CHECK table?

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

**How can I visually disable a checkbox in a SWT.CHECK table?**

I know that SWT cannot disable checkboxes per table column individually, but I managed to catch each CHECK event to uncheck the checkbox right away. Additionally, I gray out the column's text, indicating its disabled state. Even though the checkbox cannot be checked anymore, it remains enabled visually. This is the last bit that bothers me about this workaround.

Is there any hack to remove, disable, hide or overdraw the checkbox? I managed to custom-draw an image in the column, but it is displayed **under** the checkbox, so I dismissed that approach.

```
myTable.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
     logger.debug("Selection event fired.");

     if (event.detail == SWT.CHECK) {
        logger.debug("Item was checked.");

        if (null != event.item && null != event.item.getData()) {
           MyDataModel myModel = (MyDataModel)event.item.getData();
           logger.debug("Got MyDataModel object.");

           if (myModel.isDone()) {
              acknowledgmentsTable.table.setRedraw(false);

              ((TableItem)event.item).setChecked(false);
              logger.debug("Unchecked item.");

              // TODO: How to visually disable checkbox?

              acknowledgmentsTable.table.setRedraw(true);                           
           }           
        }
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with a checkbox table. You could use a normal table and use a column image to draw checked / unchecked / disabled images yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to add click listeners to image then?

Comment: One way is to use a separate column with a `CheckboxCellEditor`